# Zend sql injection prevention

Tags: sql, zend-framework, sql-injection

Hi I have this small code fragment from a web application built on ZEND framework that is not safe since 'name' is fetched from post request. Is there a standard ZEND way to prevent special symbols in $data? Like $where has the quoteInto.

```
$name = $this->_request->getParam('name');

// update query
$data = array(
    'name' => $name
);
$where = array(
    $users->getDbAdapter()->quoteInto('user_id = ?', $userId),
);
$users->update($data, $where);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim is correct if a bit terse. :)

The $data array in an update statment in Zend_Db is broken down into bound parameters. You can find the exact code in `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract`.

There are a number of procedures involved but the array ultimately ends up in this statement.

`$set[] = $this->quoteIdentifier($col, true) . ' = ' . $val;`

where your original array was `$col => $val`

then the SQL is created:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE "
         . $this->quoteIdentifier($table, true)
         . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $set)
         . (($where) ? " WHERE $where" : '');
```

It looks reasonably secure against SQL injection.

However you can always employ `Zend_Filter_Input` with `Zend_Validate` and `Zend_Filter` to really sanitize your input values.

Comment: Terse answers are my speciality :). However I think yours is a bit misleading. The `$set[]..` line you included only shows the column name being escaped. The actual value is escaped later since the query being created uses prepared statements. Suggesting Zend_Filter/Validate to 'really sanitize input values' implies the code example may not be 100% protected against SQL injection, but it is. IMHO the validation and filtering components serve a different purpose (e.g. stripping out HTML, validating email addresses).

Comment: You are correct of course, I wasn't going for absolute correctness just a better feel for what was happening and maybe getting them to look at the code (You could take hours tracing the path a query takes through these classes). After looking at the question again I thought it might be prudent to mention Zend_Filter_Input as I'm not sure the OP was asking the question we think they were asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is safe from SQL injection. `Zend_Db` treats the array you pass to `update()` as an array of named parameters, so these values are escaped automatically.